# Orbit recognition error in planet motion

Tags: numerical-integration, astronomy

```
ClearAll;
ri = 5; h = 3.33; mu = 5.678; tmax = 5.;
eqn = {R''[t] - R[t] TH'[t]^2 == -mu/R[t]^2, R'[0] == 4.5, R[0] == ri,
    TH'[t] R[t]^2 == h, TH[0] == 3 Pi/4};
NDSolve[eqn, {TH, R}, {t, 0, tmax}];
{r[u_], th[u_]} = {R[u], TH[u]} /. First[%];
ParametricPlot[r[t] {Cos[th[t]], Sin[th[t]] }, {t, 0, tmax}]
Plot[{r[t], th[t]}, {t, 0, tmax}]
```

Tried to model planet motion using coupled $ (r,\theta) $ standard Newton equations with some constants.

$$ \ddot {r} - \dot{\theta}^2\,r = - \mu/r^2 ;\, r^2 \, \dot{\theta} = h \,;$$

Results do not look like any conic. $\theta $ does not change, where may be the error? Thanks for finding the error. Should boundary condition for $ \dot r$ be from its integrand?

EDIT 1 :

It works alright with a second order  $\theta$. There is no coding error.

$$ \ddot {r} - \dot{\theta}^2\,r = - \mu/r^2 ;\quad 2 \dot {r} {\dot \theta} + \ddot {\theta} r =0;\, $$

```
ri=5;h=3.33;mu=5.678;tmax=18;
eqn={R''[t]-R[t] TH'[t]^2==-mu/R[t]^2, R[t] TH''[t]+2R'[t] TH'[t]==0,R'[0]==-.5,R[0]==ri,TH'[0]==h/ri^2,TH[0]==3Pi/4}
NDSolve[eqn,{TH,R},{t,0,tmax}];
{r[u_],th[u_]}={R[u],TH[u]}/.First[%];
ParametricPlot[r[t]{Cos[th[t]],Sin[th[t]]},{t,0,tmax}]
Plot[th'[t] r[t]^2,{t,0,tmax}]
Plot[{r[t],th[t]},{t,0,tmax}]
```

I am at a total loss to understand  why  Runge-Kutta integration needs  $\theta$ to match $r$ to a second order for it to work. Shall appreciate any comments.

EDIT2:

As mentioned in comments there was no error at all , neither in code nor in the order of $\theta$ in ODE. Initial value R'[0]= 4.5 gives a hyperbola in its asymptote region that looks like a straight radial ray. Next when initial condition  as R'[0]= - 0.5 was given resulting in an ellipse, the earlier non-recognition (by all!) could  be recognized.The question is resolved now and can be closed.

EDIT3:

So it was due to shape recognition error as can be seen by varying initial $r^{\prime}$ and sign of $t_{max}$. The following are integrands of single order $\theta$ ODEs. Numerically the first orbit has $ e= 0.6094 $

[image: Orbits with $ r^{\prime}s $ varied]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9e8y.png)

Comment: @Narasimham Your syntax is fine, I made a mistake. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: OK.. I am wondering about the need for second order derivative of $\theta$, I remember it worked before with first order.

Comment: Got it now!!  $R'[0] = - 0.5 $ gives the same solution even for ODE as the first order $ \theta  $. Also  $R'[0] = 4.5 $  is straight portion of hyperbola asymptote that I mistook for a straight line.

Comment: For me both versions (first or second order in $\theta$) run and one gets identical results with identical inital conditions. What was your problem with the first oder $\theta$-System?

Comment: I have no problem remaining now. As explained in comments above I thought the somewhat straight line orbit was wrong as  it could not be recognized as part of hyperbola orbit . Now the changed boundary conditions result in a recognizable ellipse.

Comment: @Narasimham I am experiencing one problem. If I take your original equation and set `R'[0]=-0.5` and `tmax=18` I produce functions `r[t]` and `th[t]` that overlay the edit results when I plot them. The same is true for the first and second derivatives. So what is the problem? I don't understand why but when I plot `Plot[th'[t] r[t]^2, {t, 0, tmax}]` from the first and second equations I get a very different plot!! I can't understand this as when I plot `th'[t]` from the first and second as well as `r[t]^2` from the first and second they are identical??? See if you get the same thing please.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "overlay" .. is it the same you mean? The very same results are obtained with first and second derivative formulations. When we stipulate same  initial $ θ′[0]=h/ ri^2=h / R[0]^2 $  for second derivative formulation also as input, why should you get a different plot? You should get 3.33 constant for both cases on y-axis of plot. Please check it once again.